# Galactic Dynamics: spherical coordinates velocity integral help!

Tags: astrophysics, velocity, integration, galaxies

I have been studying galactic dynamics and the following is an extract from Binney and Tremmaine's 'Galactic Dynamics' book. 
I have been having some trouble to understand how in the (4.37) integrals, the highlighted parts came to be. I mean, how are they explicitly equal to each other ? 
I am aware it has something to do with **solid angle dependence** but I am not exactly sure so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thank you for your time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll work with normal Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ and polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ for convenience where $x$ and $y$ correspond to $v_{\theta}$ and $v_{\phi}$ and $r$ corresponds to $v_t$ (nothing to do with the $r$ in the book).

The first integral just uses the standard change of variables to polar coordinates. If $f(r)$ is some function which does not depend on $\theta$ (just as the DF only depends on $v_t$) we have

$$\int \mathrm{d}^2\boldsymbol{x} f(r)=\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \,r f(r)=2\pi\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \,f(r)$$

which explains the first result.

The second is similar. Firstly we have

$$\int \mathrm{d}x \,x^2\int \mathrm{d}y \,f(r)=\int \mathrm{d}^2\boldsymbol{x}\,x^2 f(r)=\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \,r x^2f(r)$$

However, by symmetry (as $f$ depends only on $r$) this is equal to

$$\int \mathrm{d}x \int \mathrm{d}y \,y^2f(r)=\int \mathrm{d}^2\boldsymbol{x}\,y^2 f(r)=\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \,r y^2f(r).$$

Equating the two gives

$$\int \mathrm{d}x \,x^2\int \mathrm{d}y \,f(r)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \,r(x^2+y^2) f(r)\\=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \,r^3 f(r)=\pi\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \,r^3 f(r)$$

which explains the second result.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It's all clear now :')